# How can I calculate a percentage from values obtained by 2 different queries in SSMS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, pivot

First query:

```
select COUNT(EUpdate) 
from EmpUpdates 
where EProj = 'abc' and EID = '101';
```

Second query:

```
select COUNT(EProj) 
from EmpUpdates 
where EID = '101';

percentage = (first query / second query) * 100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation. Unless there are `null` values in `eupdate` and `eproj`, I would recommend `avg()`

```
select avg(case when eproj = 'abc' then 100.0 else 0 end) res
from empupdates 
where eid = 101
```

If you really need to deal with `null`s:

```
select 100.0 * count(case when eproj = 'abc' then eupdate end) / count(eproj) res
from empupdates 
where eid = 101
```

I removed the single quotes around `eid`, because it looks like a number; if it's really a string, then you can revert that change.

Answer (score 0):

You could use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT 100.0*COUNT(CASE WHEN EProj = 'abc' AND EID = '101' THEN EUpdate END) /
             COUNT(CASE WHEN EID = '101' THEN Eproj END) AS percentage
FROM EmpUpdates;
```